# Calculated table doesn't respond to filter from what-if parameter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with date ranging over the past 5 years. I want to create a new table from the existing one, but only want to return values that correspond to a certain date period based on selected value from a what-if parameter in my report.
Whenever I add the what-if parameter the table return empty, but when I hard-code the integer value into the filter it works fine. A sample of my dax query is below:

```
Filtered Table =
CALCULATETABLE (
    'Job Items',
    FILTER (
        'Job Items',
        'Job Items'[created_at].[Date]
            > TODAY () - 'Days Back'[Days Back Value]
    )
)
```

The 'Days Back Value' represents how far back a user wants the new table result, the expected value for this what-if value (Days Back Value) is an integer and I expected it to work just fine but doesn't. If I replace the value in the DAX query with a hard-coded integer it produces the expected result.

But I don't need it hard-coded because I want the new table result to be filtered based on users' selection from the what-if measure

Comment: Why is is that you need a dynamic table? What is your actual problem (the problem to which this you are asking about is not a possible solution)?

Answer (score 0):

**Calculated Columns** and **Calculated Tables** are different from **Measures**: You can filter them, but they do not recalculate on filter changes. This is why you can use constants only in your formula.